# How to extract date from filename with extenstion using shell script

Tags: shell

I tried to extract date from filenames for first two rows only with extension .log
ex: filenames are as follows
my_logFile.txt contains

```
abc20140916_1.log
abhgg20140914_1.log
abf20140910_1.log
log.abc_abc20140909_1
```

The code I tried:

```
awk '{print substr($1,length($1)-3,4)}' my_logFile.txt
```

But getting op as:

```
.log
.log
.log
```

Need op as:

```
20140916
20140914
```

*******revised query***
I have a txt file containing n number of log files. Each line in txt file is like this.

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 abchost abchost 241315175 Apr 16 10:45 abc20140405_1.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 abchost abchost 241315175 Apr 16 10:45 aghtff20140404_1.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 abchost abchost 241315175 Apr 16 10:45 log.pqrs20140403_1
```

I need to extract date out of file names from only first two rows. Here the filename has varying number of char before date.
The op should beL

```
20140405
20140404
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Give more representative data. Also, first two rows? Why don't you do `head -2 file` for that?

Comment: fedorqui - I have updated my question

Comment: OK. See my answer with `head -2` and catching the values before `.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work to you?

```
$ head -2 file | grep -Po ' [a-z]+\K[0-9]+(?=.*\.log$)'
20140405
20140404
```

#### Explanation

- `head -2 file` gets the first two lines of the file.
- `grep -Po ' [a-z]+\K[0-9]+(?=.*\.log$)'` gets the set of digits in between a block of (`space` + `a-z letters`) and (`.log` + `end of line`).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
cut -f9 -d " " <file> | grep -o -E "[0-9]{8}"
```

worked on my machine,

```
[root@giam20 ~]# cat sample.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 abchost abchost 241315175 Apr 16 10:45 abc20140405_1.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 abchost abchost 241315175 Apr 16 10:45 aghtff20140404_1.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 abchost abchost 241315175 Apr 16 10:45 log.pqrs20140403_1
[root@giam20 ~]# cut -f9 -d " " sample.txt | grep -o -E "[0-9]{8}"
20140405
20140404
20140403
```

Comment: `grep -o -E "[0-9]{8}" my_logFile.txt` is sufficient and simpler given the input data

Comment: nachiket - it is not working at my machine.. I have updated my question above.